# Create two columns with unique values and draw lines between them based on relation - Visually

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the data as below. This is a sample one. Based on this relation, we need to create two columns with unique values and then map them using arrows or lines based on relation in the below table.

It is very difficult using excel to do this manually for huge chunk. Please help me how to implement this using Python

```
Company_Name         Relation_Field
A                    Bat
B                    Camel
C                    Parrot
D                    Phone
A                    Wicket
B                    Dog
```

***Please refer to this image for desired output[image: Required Output]***

Comment: how is the output supposed to look like?

Comment: It should be as mentioned in the image above. It can be a graph or it an be anything but it should be like the one mentioned as -"Please refer to this image for desired output" in the description above

Comment: See if this library - [pydot](https://pythonhaven.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/generating_graphs_with_pydot/) seems useful

Comment: See : [Use Graphviz to show two tables adjacent to each other with lines between cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462525/use-graphviz-to-show-two-tables-adjacent-to-each-other-with-lines-between-cells)